# Method of images

Tags: electrostatics, method-of-images

[image]

we know this classic problem shown.
Where a conducting infinite sheet has a charge q in front of it at distance d.

We know how to solve this using method of images for the region A where the charge q is.
but my doubt is
will the same procedure work for the region B ?

my intuition is that the electric field is zero in region B as the infinite conducting sheet will be shielding the effect of charge q ??

any way to justify my guess using boundary conditions ?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intuition is right. The justification that we zero field in the conductor, and since we can see that the sheet is grounded, we require the electric potential to be zero in the sheet. Thus if we require continuity of the potential we get zero field in the region B.
We do not use the method of images to solve for region B, I mean we could but since we have no charge in the B region the method of images would yield zero field in the B region.

Comment: thanks for your answer.